# how to clear screen inside drawer navigator in react native

Tags: react-native

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: customstack,
    navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: () => null}
  },

  ContactAdmin : {screen : ContactAdmin},

  ResetPasswordScreen: {
    screen: ResetPassword,
    navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: 'Reset Password',}
  },

  LogoutScreen: {
    screen: Logout,
    navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: 'Logout',}
  },
  NoNetwork : { screen : NoNetwork }
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
       gesturesEnabled: true,
     style: {
      leftDrawerWidth: 40,
    },
    drawerPosition :"left",   contentComponent:SideMenu,
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
      },
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({


         headerTitle: (
           <View style={{flexDirection : 'row',flex :1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Image style={{width: 70, height: 40,backgroundColor:'white'}}  source={require('./logo.png')} />
          </View>
          ),
           headerLeft:(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
                         <Image style={{width: 25, height: 25,marginLeft:15}}  source={require('./menu.png')} />
                         </TouchableOpacity>),
           headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#008000'
                     }
           })
  },

  );

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Signup: {screen: Signup},
  Home: {screen: drawerNavigator,

         },

}, {
  initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',

})

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack)
export default AppNavigator;
```

Above code is used as a navigator for my application.Now in drawer navigator when i goes inside reset password and after successful operation i send to login screen like this.

```
await AsyncStorage.removeItem('uname', (err) => {

          this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")
          });
```

Uptil now everthing is working fine.Main problem arises when after entering new credentials in login screen.It does not takes me to HomeScreen but on resetpassword screen only.Why this is happening.After successful login i called

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")
```

But then also it is going in reset password.How can i clear drawernavigation so that again after re logging with new password it don't take to previous screen i.e. ResetPassword

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a reset, here is an example from their documentation on how to do this. We want to do this because we want to prevent from going back to the previous state and instead start with a brand new navigation state.

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

And a link here to the said example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html